# RedirectFromPage do not work with special chars in the ReturnUrl

Tags: c#, ssrs-2008, form-authentication

I am working on a form based auth module for MS SQL reporting Services which is described here:

So far so good, but I run into this problem.
The URL I call redirect to the login page to authenticate and then the page redirect back to the return url.

URL sample call:

```
http://thor/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fSampleUserReport&rs:Command=Render
```

This line crash:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(m_username, false);
```

Exception:

```
System.Web.HttpException: Der für die Umleitung von Anforderungen angegebene Rückgabe-URL ist ungültig.
   bei System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.GetReturnUrl(Boolean useDefaultIfAbsent)
   bei System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(String userName, Boolean createPersistentCookie)
   bei TQsoft.Windows.Products.SSRS.Authentication.Logon.ServerBtnLogon_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

So after investigating and debugging I found out if I skip `&rs:Command=Render` it works.

So the only special char in there I can imagine making problem is the `:` char.

Any idea how to make it work since reporting services are working with those in the navigation a lot.

**UPDATE**

It turns out that I have to redirect myself like this:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"].Replace(":","%3A"));
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

But this throws another exception:

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Der Thread wurde abgebrochen.
   bei System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   bei System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   bei System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   bei System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse)
   bei System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url)
   bei TQsoft.Windows.Products.SSRS.Authentication.Logon.ServerBtnLogon_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I am really a rookie on asp.net, but start to hate it while RoR wins atm to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue before but with hebrew char that I wanted to pass using URL link.

Try to convert the char using `%3A`.

**Edit**

I use [Google translate](http://translate.google.com) to convert those chars: just write the chars/String, hit translate and copy the relevant part in the URL.

Comment: That works, thanks so far. But this brings me to another issue to handle and parse the returnUrl all the time :S Any solution for this :)?

Comment: Sorry, but I never handle with returnUrl situations before :S

Comment: mark your question as answer as it brought me the right approach. I kicked those FormAuthentication stuff and do it all manually. Imho it is a bug in the framework that it won't urlencode the ReturnUrl.

Answer (score 0):

`Response.Redirect(HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]));`

does this work for you, replacing characters such as a question mark (?), ampersand (&), slash mark (/), and spaces.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/zttxte6w.aspx

Comment: The question is even more why the default FormAuthentication does not urlencode and throws an exception. There is no way to deal with this using the default methods :S

Comment: And btw, I can't urlencode it again, because the reporting services encode some chars, but not all, do it again will result in chaos I fear.

Comment: have you tried Response.Redirect(HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"])) ? Works?

Comment: The encode is not the case atm, my page do not even redirect, the url is correct now. So I can not use FormAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage and redirect throw an exception or if I move it to the end of my code it does nothing.